Investment TV show
I am trying to remember a show I watched a year or two back, but I cannot remember what it is called.
I was hoping that somebody would be able to help me identify it.
The show:
Two people come to this guy(main investor) and throw a short pitch about what they would use the money towards, etc. The guy then supports 1 of the 2 to invest into and we then follow that investment to see what his returns were. 
There might be another investor who invests in the other one and they compare the results, but I am not sure.
Any help would be great, I am willing to try to answer any questions to make this question more clear.

American? European?

If the two investors go out to the inventors, then I'd suggest it's Invention USA as Luis has answered.

A few questions: Approximate year of show? When did you first see it? What location is the show, e.g. American/Europe? How long were the episodes?

Gah, I wish I really could provide helpful information... I only saw 2 episodes of it or so, and that was about a year or so ago, so it can be a couple of years old or more (if it was reruns...). Its in the united states, and I THINK the episodes are an hour long (only based on the fact that they were covering a lot of things every episode)

Could it be Invention USA?

For centuries, America has been an engine of invention and innovation, creating technology that has shaped world history. From Ben Franklin to the Wright brothers, from Thomas Edison to Steve Jobs, the United States has been a constant generator of revolutionary ideas. To this day, in basements and backyards around the country, Americans are striving to turn their dreams into the next big thing.

Invention USA follows Reichart Von Wolfsheild and Garrett Lisi, both innovators and scientists with ties to investors, as they go in search of the next breakthrough invention. Whether they're traveling the country to visit garage innovators at home or meeting with inventors at their Los Angeles testing lab, Reichart and Garrett will put prototypes to the test and give a tough, no-nonsense evaluation of each invention's potential. If they like what they see, they'll invest to help bring the product to market. The stakes are high and dreams are on the line: Every idea has the potential to change someone's life... or even the world.
See this blog, i think that corresponds to your clues.

This doesn't seem to be it either. It's not about inventing, but more about  investing in people. One sample investment was about a guy throwing a rodeo or concert of some sort thinking he will be making big bucks... he was given x amount of weeks to promote, etc...its showed the difficulties promoting, the weather etc. The show you provided seems very interesting though, so if the correct answer does not appear by the end of the bounty time I will make sure to bounty you up ;)

I've seen a few episodes of this TV Show but don't remember that episode, but I think that TV show may be the same as the one that you are looking for.

I believe you are talking about the show "Shark Tank".
Basically, there are 4 self made multi millionaires, and they form a panel to listen to pitches from aspiring entrepreneurs. The entrepreneurs come in and give the sales pitch, what they are looking for in an investment, and what they are willing to give in return.
The panel can buy into their product singly, in combination, reject it out right, and/or counter offer. 
They also have some rotating guests, which have included Jeff Foxworthy and Mark Cuban.
If it is not Shark Tank, then it may be "The Profit" which is a single investor, or you can look at these 10 business reality shows: "Shark Tank Wannabes"

mm, no. It's similar to shark tank and dragons den, but its 2 people pitching seperate ideas, and throughout the episode we can watch them carry out their idea and see if it worked.
Thanks for the reply! I hope you know what show im takling about :)

@TheOneWhoPrograms - I edited it while you were typing, see if the link I had has it.

Hmm, sadly it doesn't appear to be any. The profit seems to focus on businesses, and it seems like he just picks one...similar to things liek bar rescue, while the show im thinking about has 2 people and the ideas range, I THINK one of the ideas was something like an event on a farm, and the guy invested in him and you can see the process of setting up the event, the difficulties, etc..then at the end of the show we find out if the investment payed off or if the other one would have been better.
